# Failed to increase date by one hour

Tags: linux, date

I'm having an interesting issue with date command in my script. My script generates loads of hourly data form a given date range. I use date function to increase "from" date by an hour till it hits "to" date. The date method works just fine and increased the "from" date by an hour as I expected. However, it stops increasing once it reaches 2017/11/05 01:00:00. I haven't tested whole lot of dates yet, but the other date that has the same issue is 2016/11/06 01:00:00.

```
$ date -d "2017/11/05 01:00:00 1 hour" +"%Y/%m/%d %T"
2017/11/05 01:00:00

$ date -d "2016/11/06 01:00:00 1 hour" +"%Y/%m/%d %T"
2016/11/06 01:00:00
```

**Linux version**
Linux 3.10.0-229.4.2.el7.x86_64

Comment: I don't have that issue. (`date (GNU coreutils) 8.25`)

Comment: I tried the same thing under git bash and cygwin (CYGWIN_NT-10.0-WOW 703CSQ2 1.7.35(0.287/5/3) ) and I'm still getting the same issue.

Comment: @RoVo are you from non daylight saving country?

Comment: You can help answerers by adding a `%z` to both format strings and [edit]ing the consequent output into the question.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, it's DST (Daylight saving time) causing this issue. When I pass DST date 1 am (First Sunday of November) to date command, it probably increases the date by an hour internally and deduct one hour from it for DST. Solution is to use -u (UTC) as suggested by @jkan5855.

```
$ date -d "2017/11/05 01:00:00 1 hour" +"%Y/%m/%d %T" -u
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `date --version` to see which version of date you're flying with.
The command on `date (GNU Coreutils) 8.30` works fine

Reinstall or update GNU Coreutils (find the appropriate package for your linux/subsystem), as nobody else is getting this issue apparently. Your exact command prints out `2017/11/05 02:00:00` for me.

If that doesn't fix it, is your computer temporarily date-impaired. I have no better way of describing it, but try restarting your computer, since you're also getting this on other subsystems/terminals.

Comment: are you happen to be in a location where DST doesn't apply?

Comment: No, I'm in Eastern European Summer Time right now, so it definitively does apply. Are you in Canada, cuba, haiti or other country where DST ended 11-05 in 2017?

Comment: Definitely it caused by DST. Because all the dates I'm having issue with coincide with DST date (First sunday of November)

Comment: alright. run `date --version` and give me the output

Comment: date (GNU coreutils) 8.22

Comment: For some reason I don't get the same result when using my DST date and time. Try doing all the dates with -u and repeat the hour twice near DST as clocks are turned 1 hour backwards so the clock goes 23 0 1 1 2 3 4 with double ones

Comment: Sorry I missed your first question. Yes, I'm from one of those countries.

Comment: using UTC as you suggested seems to resolve the problem. I'll try with more dates and let you know.